# add selected multi category name to url with "-" separator automatically Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hi my app requires showing posts of multi-category select. when user checks category checkbox, posts page refreshes and showing posts that belongs to selected category and when user checks other category checkbox, page refreshes and showing posts that belongs to both selected categories, in my scenario url must be like:

http://localhost:8000/posts?&cat_Name=sport-economic

I've Got url and explode to an array with "-" separator and works fine when I add cat_Name parameters to url manually with "-".
my question is how can do this automatically that mean when I select categories automatically add name of selected categories to cat_Name parameter with "-" separator like Previous url?
relationship between post and category is many-to-many

**Checkbox form in blade:**

```
<form action="{{ url('/posts-filter') }}" method="post">{{ csrf_field() }}
    <h3>categories</h3>
    <ul id="tree1">
        @foreach($categories as $category)
            @if(!empty($_GET['cat']))
                <?php $categoryArr = explode('-',$_GET['cat']) ?>
                @if(in_array($category,$categoryArr))
                    <?php $categorycheck="checked"; ?>
                @else
                    <?php $categorycheck=""; ?>
                @endif
            @else
                <?php $categorycheck=""; ?>
            @endif
            <li>
                <input name="categoryFilter[]" onchange="javascript:this.form.submit();" id="{{ $category->id }}" value="{{ $category->name }}" type="checkbox" {{ $categorycheck }}>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="products-colors">{{ $category->name }}</span>
                @if(count($category->childs) )
                    @include('news.cat',['childs' => $category->childs])
                @endif
            </li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</form>
```

**Filter function that fetch form request:**

```
    public function filter(Request $request){

        $data = $request->all();
        $cat_Name="";
        if(!empty($data['categoryFilter'])){
            foreach($data['categoryFilter'] as $cat){
                if(empty($cat_Name)){
                    $cat_Name = "&cat_Name=".$cat;
                }else{
                    $cat_Name .= "-".$cat;
                }
            }
        }

        $finalUrl = "posts"."?".$cat_Name;
        return redirect::to($finalUrl);
    }
```

**Posts function:**

```
public function posts(Request $request){
    $categories = Category::where([
        ['type', '=', 'post'],
        ['parent_id', '=', 0],
    ])->get();
    if(!empty($request->input('cat_Name'))){
        $categoryArray = explode('-', $request->input('cat_Name'));
        $news = News::whereHas('categories', function($q) use ($categoryArray) {
            return $q->whereIn('name', $categoryArray);
        })->get();

    }else{
        $posts = Post::where('status', 'published')->paginate(5);
    }

    return view('post.index',compact('posts','categories'));
}
```

My code problem is one category display each time in url and not addition to past url cat_Name with "-" separator

Comment: Query parameters are able to handle multiple values for the same form input. I don't know why you're overcomplicating this with the `-` separator. If you change your name to `name="cat_name[]"`, then allow `multiple="true"`, when you select values and submit the form, you'll have `&cat_name[]=1&cat_name[]=2...`, and you won't have to explode then query. Also, what happens if your category name has a `-` in it? Your current logic just won't work for that, but the new approach will use `id` instead of `name`, so that won't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use "-" as a seperator because you need to write a bunch of code to fix default browser/interpreter behaviour.

If you use a checkbox, like your example (simplified):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="category[]" onchange="javascript:this.form.submit();" value="{{ $category->name }}"> {{ $category->name }}
```

Once you change one of the values, it should generate an url like this:

`/posts?category[]=sport`

`/posts?category[]=sport&category[]=economic`

On your controller you can access them using the default `$request` object:

```
if ($categories = $request->category ) {
    $news = News::whereHas('categories', function ($q) use ($categories) {
        return $q->whereIn('name', $categories);
    })->get();
}
```

If you want to use a url-friendly filter url, you could take a look at [Spatie's Laravel Query Builder](https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-query-builder/v2/features/filtering/) and eg. the [VUE API Query](https://github.com/robsontenorio/vue-api-query) package to create nicer URL's. However, this can get pretty complicated fast so I'd stick to the defaults as suggested above.